# Can I get a student visa through the Spanish Embassy in New Delhi?

Tags: spain, study, applications, long-stay-visas

I am a Nepali citizen, trying to apply for a student visa at the Spanish Embassy in India. How long does it take to get a student visa that is for more than 90 days but less than 180 days? Can a Nepali get a long term visa through the embassy?

Answer (score 2):

I [read in the web of the Spanish embassy in Delhi](http://www.exteriores.gob.es/Embajadas/NUEVADELHI/es/Noticias/Paginas/Articulos/CAMBIO-DE-EMPRESA-ADJUDICATARIA-DE-CONTRATO-DE-COOPERACI%C3%93N-POR-PARTE-DE-UN-PROVEEDOR-DE-SERVICIOS-EXTERNO-EN-LA-RECEPCI%C3%93N-Y.aspx) that from December, 17th 2016 the company in charge of visas for this embassy is BLS International Services.

In [their site](https://india.blsspainvisa.com/) you have lots of information. For example in their [FAQs page](https://india.blsspainvisa.com/faq.php) they explain.

> **How early can I apply?**
>   Applicants are free to apply up to 90 days prior to their date of travel. However, all applications must be submitted at least 15 working days prior to the proposed date of travel to accommodate any unforeseen processing delays.
>
> **How long do I have to wait for the Visa once I submit my application?**
>   After submission of the visa application, if there be need, further documents can be requested to the applicant. Please note as per the instructions received from Embassy of Spain minimum processing time is 15 working days (It may delay depending on case to case).

Comment: Is it possible to get an urgent student visa? For example , when I applied for Chinese visa, they asked me if I wanted to apply the regular visa or the urgent one. I checked on the Spanish embassy website, but can't seem to find anything.

Comment: @nanana I cannot find any reference in the website. You may try to contact them and ask.

Comment: How strict is the Spanish Embassy in New Delhi about submitting the visa application on time? They are so inefficient and incompetent tbh. I need to be in Madrid on 22nd August however my college has given me permission to arrive late but I must be there by 29th Aug anyhow. I couldn't get any slot for appointment before 3rd August. When I emailed them earlier they didn't mention that the applications should be presented at least a month before the program starts. Only today they stated this thing via email. I couldn't even find anything like this online. I'm in such a dilemma now.

Comment: @nanana I am sorry to read this. I would try to talk with the college, since I am quite sure they will be understanding your situation. Provide all the paperwork you've been doing to uphold your claims. Regarding the Spanish Embassy, they tend to be plainly horrible. Again, talk with the BLS company and see.